# CruiseControl.net : Using SvnLabeller / SvnRevisionLabeller

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm setting up a new project using CruiseControl.net 1.4.

I see from [ccnet contributions](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNETCOMM/Contributions)
that there are two options for a subversion repository number labeller - a
feature that I would really like to make use of.

1) SVNLabeller available from [jcxsoftware](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/jcx/ccnet-dev)

and

2) Svnrevisionlabeller available from [google code](http://code.google.com/p/svnrevisionlabeller/)

My problem is that (1) claims support for ccnet 1.4 but I can't find
any documentation on how to configure it.

(2) comes with documentation but does not claim to support ccnet 1.4

Can anyone help me with either how to configure SVNLabeller or tell me
if Svnrevisionlabeller works with 1.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is David Keaveny, author/maintainer of SvnRevisionLabeller. I use it against v1.4.2 on a daily basis at work, so I think it's safe to say that it works OK. I should probably update the Google Code site to reflect this.

**Update**: I've updated the project wiki to reflect this. Oh, and I'm also picking up on a bunch of feature requests, so keep an eye open for a new release in the near future.

Comment: Any chance of it working the CTP of 1.5? My brief trial suggests it doesn't yet? I'd offer to help out if I could get some pointers, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [David Keaveny’s Blog Post](http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/cruisecontrolnet-and-subversion-svnrevisionlabeller/) regarding the SVNRevisionLabeller? The link will take you to a detailed post on it's usage.

We are currently testing this utility against the current release (1.4) of CCNet without any problems, i.e. it's producing the correct revision and build labels appended to the major/minor digits we specify.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of SVNLabeler. You can get a 1.5 version here:

http://svn.jcxsoftware.com/node/216

Here is how you use it:

```
  <labeller type="SvnLabeller">
    <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>2</MinorVersion>
    <BuildNumber>3</BuildNumber>
    <workingDirectory>c:\path to your code</workingDirectory>
    <executable>c:\path to\svn.exe</executable>
  </labeller>
```

The version comes out as:

1.2.3.SVN_REVISION_NUMBER

Good luck,

Juan